# How should I derive the Euler-Lagrange equation by using the Gateaux differential?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, gateaux-derivative

Find the Gateaux differential for the functional $ S[y]=y(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(4y'^2+x^2y^2)dx, y(1)=2 $ and use it to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation. Be sure to specify all boundary conditions that the stationary path must satisfy.

Here's my work:

We have $ S[y+\epsilon h]=y(0)+\epsilon h(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}[4(y'+\epsilon h')^2+x^2(y+\epsilon h)^2]dx $.

Hence $ \frac{d}{d\epsilon}S[y+\epsilon h]=h(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}[8(y'+\epsilon h')h'+2x^2(y+\epsilon h)h]dx $.

Thus $ \bigtriangleup S[y, h]=h(0)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(8y'h'+2x^2yh)dx $,

so the Gateaux differential is $ \bigtriangleup S[y, h]=h(0)+\int_{0}^{1}(4y'h'+x^2yh)dx $.

And now I'm stuck. How should I use this Gateaux differential to derive the associated Euler-Lagrange equation? And how to specify all boundary conditions that the stationary path must satisfy?

Comment: Integrate by parts to get everything in the integral multiplying $h$. Since $h$ is arbitrary and the statement is true for all $h$, everything multiplying it must be identically $0$

Comment: But what about $h(0)$? What should be the value of $h(0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for $y + \varepsilon h$ to be admissable, $h(1)$ must be $0$. Now take the last expression and integrate by parts $$\delta S[y;h] = h(0) + \int_0^14y'h' + x^2yh~\mathrm{d}x = h(0) + \int_0^1(-4y'' + x^2y)h~\mathrm{d}x + 4y'(1)h(1) - 4y'(0)h(0).$$
For $y$ to be an extremal of this functional, this quantity must be zero for every admissible $h$. By choosing $h$ with compact support on $(0,1)$, we can see that the integral must be zero, which implies that $-4y'' + x^2y = 0$ identically on $(0,1)$. However, some admissible $h$ may be nonzero at $0$, so more conditions on $y$ are required to ensure the boundary terms are zero.

First notice that $h(1)$ is zero via the definition of admissible perturbations. The remaining boundary terms are $$h(0) - 4hy'h(0) = (1 - 4y'(0))h(0).$$
Since $h(0)$ is arbitrary, this can only be zero for all $h$ if $1-4y'(0) = 0\implies y'(0) = 1/4.$ The complete Euler-Lagrange equation is then $$-4y'' + x^2y=0, \\ y'(0) = \frac{1}{4}, \quad y(1) = 2.$$

Comment: But how did you get the term $ -4y'' $?

Comment: $\int_0^1 4y'h'~\mathrm{d}x = \left.y'h\right|_0^1-\int_0^1 4y''h~\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Oh, I see. Also, is it okay to simplify the Euler-Lagrange equation further, to say, $ 4y''-x^2y=0 $ with those boundary conditions?

Comment: Multiplying by $-1$ does nothing so it is fine. I default to a negative sign there so that the second derivative term is positive definite

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much for the help.